# how does keep or drop function work in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have a table with variables x1,x2,...x6, and try to keep the variables if their values are 1, or if their values is not 1, then drop them.

```
data a;unid='001'; x1=1; x2=.;x3=0; x4=10; x5=.;x6=1; run;
data aa1; set a;
  if x1=1 then do; keep x1; end;
  if x2=1 then do; keep x2; end;
  ...
  if x6=1 then do; keep x6; end;
 keep unid;
run;
data aa2; set a;
 if x1^=1 then do; drop x1;end;
 if x2^=1 then do; drop x2; end;
 ...
run;
```

I want a table:

```
unid x1 x6
001  1  1
```

however, i got different result, and just wonder how to fix, thanks!

Comment: DROP and KEEP are not executable statements.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? You cannot DROP a variable from an individual observation.  You either drop the variable from the dataset or you don't.  Show an input dataset with more than one observation.  Show the output dataset you want to create from that input.

Comment: DROP/KEEP are statements, not functions. They cannot be executed conditionally as your data set cannot drop x1 for certain observations and x2 for other. x1 and x2 are columns and are either dropped or kept, there's no in between. I think you're trying to set them to missing, which would be done via `if x1 ne 1 then call missing(x1);`.

Comment: What do you want out if there is another observation, say `unid='002'`, with x1 not equal to 1?

Comment: the question is to the table with only 1 obs, and then to drop all the variables if not equal to 1.    `data a; unid='001'; x1=1; x2=.;x3=0; x4=0; x5=.;x6=1; run;`   and need the output with 3 variables: `unid x1  x6`

Comment: just wonder if a simple way to drop the variables if they not 1 for a table with only 1 obs,

Answer (score 1):

When you submit code, a `DATA` step is automatically compiled and then run.

`DROP` and `KEEP` are statements SAS uses at compile-time.  They are not executed at run-time.

In other words, the structure of any output data set named in the `DATA` statement is set at compile-time.  The structure can not be changed at run-time.

There are similar `DROP=` and `KEEP=` data set options that can be specified for use at i/o time.  One trick is to use run-time dynamic component object `HASH` and a `.OUTPUT(dataset: dataset-name(dataset-options))` method call.

A second trick is to accumulate the list of variable names to be kept/dropped, store the list in macro variable and then use (or apply) the &list in a subsequent step.

A third trick is to transpose/filter/untranspose.